# To get contents in id

Tags: iphone, ios

In my project I am having one object of type id. I am setting different values to it. Now I need to check which value it contains and according to that I need to do the operation.

This is my code:

```
id *currentObject=nil;
-(void)setCurrentObject:(id *)object{
    currentObject=object;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {


    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"apple"]) {
    [self setCurrentObject:apple];
    return;
    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"orange"]) {
    [self setCurrentObject:orange];
        return;
    }   

    [self readString];

}

-(void) readString{

//Here I need to check contents of 'currentObject'. If it contains 'apple' then print 'Its apple' else don't do anything
}
```

How to check this content of current object which is of type 'id'?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the class name of your object by using

```
NSStringFromClass
```

you might want to determine what kind of class your ID object is

```
id object;
NSDictionary *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"test string"];
object = str;
NSString *string = NSStringFromClass([object class]);
NSLog(@"object is class of : %@", string);

if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"data string = %@",(NSString*)object);
}else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    NSLog(@"data dictionary = %@", (NSDictionary*)object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get object's class name you can use

```
const char* className = class_getName([yourObject class]);
```

Then create a nsstring from above classname using utf8 string then check against what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what kind of object you are going to store ("apple" or "orange"), why don't you just create a `NSString` instead of `id`? Don't forget the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).